# como obtener un view desde WindowsManager

Tags: android, android-studio

necesito alguna informacion esutve buscando como hacerlo pero no encontre nada colegas de que manera regreso un View desde un WindowsManager

Comment: Y como agregaste tu vista, con WindowsManager? Agrega el código o explica que deseas realizar con más detalle.

Comment: Gracias por responder el problema es que necesito hacer una app similares a los grabadores de pantalla como DU recorder y AZ recorder pero simplemente no encuentro informacion de como realizar una captura, si bien por razones de seguridad no se puede hacer capturas de pantalla fuera de tu aplicacion no entiendo como aplicaciones como Du recoreder pueden hacerlo

Comment: al parecer esas aplicaciones lo hacen con WindowsManager pero no estoy seguro como nuevamente espero su ayuda :)